# Social Sharing / tell a friend plug but specify which URL to share

Tags: sharing, social-sharing

while there are plenty of social sharing / email a friend type of plugins i am looking for one that will let me place it on only 1 page and most importantly allow me to specify which URL (not necessarily the URL of the page the form/buttons are on) I would like to recommend.

to explain: the site i am working on is selling an online course.  when purchased, the thank you page will have an option to tell your friends about the course.  so i don't want to share this "thank you page" i would like the user to share the home/sales page.

is there a plugin that does this or do i have to roll my own?  and if the latter, where should i start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend rolling your own.  Use the [sharethis](http://sharethis.com/) api or [addthis](http://www.addthis.com/).  Then you can use get_permalink(); for the url parameter.

```
function wpu_share() {
        $url = get_permalink();
        $title = get_the_title();
        $add_this = 'st_url="'.esc_url( $url ).'"'; ?>

    <span class='st_facebook_large' <?php echo $add_this; ?> displayText='Facebook'></span>
    <span class='st_twitter_large' <?php echo $add_this; ?>  displayText='Tweet'></span>
    <span class='st_linkedin_large' <?php echo $add_this; ?> displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
    <span class='st_email_large' <?php echo $add_this; ?> displayText='Email'></span>
    <?php }

 add_action('wp_footer', 'wpu_share_js' );
 function wpu_share_js() { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x = true;</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:"ur-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}); </script>
<? }
```

### Update

You will need to pass a variable to the thank you page that references the post id of the course they signed up for then you can use this to get the right url.

```
$url = get_permalink( $post_id );  

// You will need to pass the post id to the thank you page using a query string or another method.
```

To use a query string append ?id=$post->ID to the end of the redirect to the thank you page.  Then on the thank you page:

```
if (isset( $_GET['id'] ) $post_id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

For security make sure you use esc_url() where ever you are using the $url variable.

Comment: i don't actually want to use get_permalink()... that's what all the plugins already do. but you are right, i don't think there's anyway around adding my own.  thanks!